# I'm not sure how to get around this notice

Tags: php

When I execute the following script:

```
<?php
$num = 3;
list($num, $dec) = explode(".", $num);
?>
```

PHP says:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/www/test.php on line 3

Other than disabling these notices, is there a way I can prevent this notice from showing up?

Comment: when developing, don't turn off warnings. try to change to code to cope with the standard

Comment: Quite what are you trying to do? Your code does not make sense.

Comment: This code does in fact make sense.. @staticsan

Comment: @KorvinSzanto Yes, now that I've seen another answer, I can understand what he's trying to do. Still, an explanation of what is desired would be good for the OP to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$num = 3;

// forces to show the decimal point
$rnum = sprintf("%1\$.2f",$num);

list($num, $dec) = explode(".", $rnum);
```

EDIT for completeness:

alternatively you can also use number_format:

```
$rnum = number_format($num, 2);
```

as suggested by Bojan Dević

Comment: This is an interesting solution, I wouldn't have thought to go to sprintf.

Comment: Works perfect! Your format is a little different though, than most of the [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) I'm looking over. Would you mind walking me through each piece of this: "%1\$.2f" Thank you.

Comment: @Joncom sprintf is a powerfull function. I invite you to see the complete reference http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php :)

Comment: You can also use number_format like: `$rnum = number_format($num, 2);`

Comment: @BojanDević If you're agree I edit my answer adding your alternative solution for completeness. Otherwise you can insert another answer :) np for me.

Answer (score 1):

This notice is telling you that you only have a single array value, one way to solve this would be to use array_pad:

```
list($num, $dec) = array_pad(explode('.', $num),2,0);
```

[Here's a working example](http://3v4l.org/kfi66).

Comment: A retaliatory downvote is childish, and takes away from this site as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

While your code doesnt make actual sense, Im going to assume that you've done it as a quick way to produce an error.

If you added your first line of code to be

```
ini_set('display_errors','0');
```

this supresses the display of errors - however, you should only do this once your project is done and deployed at the end.. otherwise you then dont suffer from the "why is it an empty page" or "why did it not do.."

Comment: This is not a sufficient way to program, this issue can easily be solved without masking the problem.

Comment: Doing it at the end of the project doesn't change the fact that you're not doing it correctly, you should never jump to the least realistic conclusion.

Comment: Not only does it mask all problems; it is a problem. I gave you a downvote because this isn't a solution to the problem, the OP explicitly asked "Other than disabling these notices, is there a way I can prevent this notice from showing up?", you did not answer the question, you are simply giving him some info that he already had.

Comment: Actually that WAS his question. How do you hide errors. Not, please explain why the code I wrote didnt work - hence my first line..